# Search for coincidence in any column with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find all coincidences in any column with Postgres? Something like:
`SELECT u FROM users u where <u.anyfield like 'KEY_WORD'>`.
I know that Postgres provides full text search with to_tsvector and to_tsquery but I think it's not my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the entire row to a text, then apply your `like` condition.

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE cast(test as text) LIKE '%KEY_WORD%';
```

**BUT** be very thoughtful about doing this... what is the point of searching IDs or clearly unrelated fields? Think about indexing too, as this query will likely have a terrible performance.